# changing the scheduled email content in mailgun

Tags: email, mailgun

Once i set delivery time in mailgun api request, is it possible to change the content of mail later before delivery. For instance - I set delivery time of 2 day(currently they allow max of 3 day delivery time) from now and then after 1 day I want to change the delivery timing/content of email, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, once an email message is queued it cannot be edited further. Thus no, you cannot reschedule an email once its been scheduled to be sent out at a particular date. Cool idea though ;)